# running external programs in Julia: < command

Tags: julia

I'm trying to redirect a local script to an external server and need to use the < command in the Julia run() command. I use |> for > in Julia, but |< does not work for <. My question is how can I use the redirect UNIX command < in Julia ?

This is in 0.3.

Thank you

Comment: As @Reza pointed out in his answer, this is one of many details that have improved in 0.4. I suggest that you move to 0.4 at your earliest convenience. (In particular, you will find that importing large packages like Gadfly is suddenly much less painful!)

Answer (score 6):

It's not clear for me how to direct STDIN in 0.3.0 ,but only for more clarity, form version 0.4.0 `|>` is marked as `deprecated` and is replaced by more robust `pipeline` function, using `pipeline` you can direct `In|OUT` like this:

```
 run(pipeline(`ls` , stdout="ot.txt"))
 run(pipeline(`sort` , stdin="ot.txt"))
```